# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Webhook'

Tags: python, selenium

I installed `dhooks` on Windows with the command:

```
pip install dhooks
```

but when it is executed it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Webhook'
```

THIS IS MY CODE BELOW:

```
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed

hook = Webhook('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/22892770896038952/ao--vUV18I_DiZCmM50SifYeGpH-sC3AYKuqtVnEE')

embed = Embed(
    description='This is the **description** of the embed! :smiley:',
    color=0x5CDBF0,
    timestamp='now'  # sets the timestamp to current time
    )

image1 = 'https://i.imgur.com/rdm3W9t.png'
image2 = 'https://i.imgur.com/f1LOr4q.png'

embed.set_author(name='Author Goes Here', icon_url=image1)
embed.add_field(name='Test Field', value='Value of the field :open_mouth:')
embed.add_field(name='Another Field', value='1234 :smile:')
embed.set_footer(text='Here is my footer text', icon_url=image1)

embed.set_thumbnail(image1)
embed.set_image(image2)

hook.send(embed=embed)
```

````
---------------------------------------------

**when I execute it gives the above error...**

> python bot.py

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user52\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\dhooks\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import Webhook
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\dhooks\client.py", line 3, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import (
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 3, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Python32\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "C:\Python32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import coroutines
  File "C:\Python32\lib\asyncio\coroutines.py", line 5, in <module>
    import inspect
  File "C:\Python32\lib\inspect.py", line 36, in <module>
    import bot
  File "C:\Users\user52\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
ImportError: cannot import name 'Webhook' from partially initialized module 'dhooks' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\dhooks\__init__.py)```

Wondering someone will help.
````

Comment: can you possibly share the code? not sure why you need selenium/ why it is in selenium tag

Comment: I added the code above;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install Webhook`

Install that first and then the module you want

If the above doesn't work ,use

`pip install webhooks`